# How can I update a Wicket DataView with AJAX?

Tags: java, ajax, wicket, dataview

I need to AJAXfully filter by users list of `PsDoctrans` which is shown in a Wicket `DataView`.

```
final TextField txtName= new TextField("user");

final PSDocDP dp = new PSDocDP("username");
DataView<PsDoctrans> dataView = new DataView<PsDoctrans>("unproc", dp)
{
    @Override
    protected void populateItem(final Item<PsDoctrans> item)
    ...
};
```

`PSDocDP` is:

```
public class PSDocDP extends SortableDataProvider<PsDoctrans>
{...}

final WebMarkupContainer wmc = new WebMarkupContainer("container"); 
wmc.add(dataView); 
wmc.setOutputMarkupId(true);

AjaxButton butFind=new AjaxButton("find"){
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
    {               
        String value=(String)txtName.getModelObject();
        dp = new PSDocDP(value);

        target.addComponent(wmc);
    }
};
```

After submitting, nothing changes. The program shows some data, but it isn't filtering. How can I make filtering happen?

Comment: yes its final, I have simplified code to be more understandable

Comment: How does the PSDocDP implementation looks like? Also @Nishant: yers, it should, the compiler should error on this.

Comment: `String value=(String)txtName.getModelObject();` are you getting value correctly? I doubt that probably model is returning nothing.

Comment: I have tried dp = new PSDocDP(null);
but nothing has changed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use constructions comparable to this, so it should work.

Do you really create a new "dp" object in the callback. You should simply change the state of the data provider - how should the component ever get the changed provider.

```
    @Override
    protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form)
    {               
        String value=(String)txtName.getModelObject();
-->        dp.setName(value);
        target.addComponent(wmc);
    }
```