# How to invoke a Javascript method after Wicket Dataview is rendered with AjaxPagingNavigator?

Tags: ajax, pagination, wicket, behavior, dataview

I am using Wicket's DataView with AjaxPagingNavigator.  My use case is very similar to

[How can I update a Wicket DataView with AJAX?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4561045/how-can-i-update-a-wicket-dataview-with-ajax)

withe the caveat that I need to do post processing after the Wicket Dataview is rendered.

What I would like to do it to invoke a Javascript after the "page" of the dataview is rendered.  So for example , when a  user clicks on "page 2" link of the AjaxPagingNavigator ,  the dataview would be rendered.  But after the data view is rendered successfully, I would like to invoke a Javascript method. How cam I do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See IHeaderContributor.
MyPanel.java:

```
@Override
public void renderHead(IHeaderResponse response) {
    response.renderOnDomReadyJavascript("some JS that will run when the page is loaded");
}
```

Comment: Thanks , your suggestion  worked withe caveat that the WebMarkupContainer enclosing the DataGrid needs to be extended to implement the  IHeaderContributor.

Comment: In Wicket 1.5 you don't need to implement it explicitly.